# Black 3D Models - Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, textures, light

I just recently started using Unity3D, and have imported this object from Sketchfab. When I imported it, it provided all the necessary textures and meshes, but it's all black as shown in the images below. It's the same case for any other object I try to add from the asset store. I've tried to fiddle with the light source, but that doesn't seem to work. Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Edit: This is what my mesh properties looks like. I have selected "pearl_body" and it's still all black.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand your model in the Hierarchy(left panel) view untill you will see Mesh Renderer component in the Inspector(right panel). Then you will be able to set the material. Probably you will need replace lambert45G in the material view with BaseTexture.
That should fix the problem.

You can read more about materials [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Materials.html), and about [mesh renderers.](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/mesh-renderers-and-mesh-filters)

Comment: After working with it, I see that the emission setting is the one that's making it all one solid color.

Comment: OMG It works :D, I just set the emission texture to "pearl_body"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution. Not sure if it will work in your particular case, but here it goes:

I had a model that worked fine in unity until I rigged it, then it looked black. What caused this was that I applied a Smooth modifier after the Skin modifier. I solved it by:

1. Saving the Skin modifier info by clicking on "Save" at the Advanced tab.
2. Reset Xform / convert to editable poly / smooth modifier (needed in my case as I forgot to use it when the model was finished, before rigging)
3. Convert to edit poly again.
4. Apply skin and load the previously saved skin file.

That's all. Cheers!